# Aligning a div inside two div with different float

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hi all I have a three divs with second div in middle of two divs with different floats.  I want the width of  second div to be occupied till the third div. I need to use width auto for the second div as this has to be same in every zoom.  Also check my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mailtoshebin/VZn4e/1/

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">1</div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="middleTop">
            <div>This div should reach till right div</div>
        </div>
        <div id="middleBottom">
            <div id="middleBottomSub">this goes right this goes right this goes right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lolo"s answer is correct but you could do it differently with `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

Get rid of `float` in #left and #right, apply `display:table-cell` instead, as well as on #middle. And apply `display:table` to #main (leave the HTML unchanged). You must also add `width:100%;` to #main to use all the horizontal space.

```
#main {
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
#left {
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#f0f;
    display:table-cell;
}
#right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#00f;
    display:table-cell;
}
#middle {
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VZn4e/4/)

This solution has the added benefit that #left and #right will expand vertically with the #middle content if you need it to (just get rid of the fixed height).

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VZn4e/5/)

Answer (score 4):

You can display `#middle` as block element, and set it's left and right margins to 50px. That will give you desired effect if you move `#right` div above `#middle`.

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#f0f;
     display:inline-block;
}
#right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:#00f;
    float: right;
     display:inline-block;
}
#middle {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">1</div>
    <div id="right">3</div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="middleTop">
            <div>This div should reach till right div</div>
        </div>
        <div id="middleBottom">
            <div id="middleBottomSub">this goes right this goes right this goes right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/VZn4e/2/